# Combining date ranges of 2 tables to a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully, a straightforward question (but with a difficult answer, I suspect).  I have 2 tables with date ranges that cover the same "overall" range, but TABLE_A has the ranges broken down a bit more initially, while TABLE_B breaks it down more later:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_A (
START_DT datetime,
END_DT datetime)

INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('4/1/1993', '4/29/1993');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('4/29/1993', '5/12/1993');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('5/13/1993', '5/26/1993');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('5/27/1993', '8/18/1993');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('2/10/1994', '2/23/1994');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('2/25/1994', '3/9/1994');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES ('3/10/1994', '5/5/1994');

CREATE TABLE #TABLE_B (
START_DT datetime,
END_DT datetime)

INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES ('4/1/1993', '5/12/1993');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES ('5/13/1993', '8/18/1993');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES ('2/10/1994', '2/22/1994');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES ('2/24/1994', '3/23/1994');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES ('3/24/1994', '4/20/1994');
INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES ('4/21/1994', '5/5/1994');
```

What I want is a TABLE_C that combines these ranges:

```
START DT      END DT    
4/1/1993       4/29/1993      FROM TABLE A
4/29/1993      5/12/1993      FROM TABLE A
5/13/1993      5/26/1993      FROM TABLE A
5/27/1993      8/18/1993      FROM TABLE A
2/10/1994      2/22/1994      FROM TABLE A or TABLE B
2/23/1994       3/9/1994      FROM TABLE A
3/10/1994      3/23/1994      START DT FROM TABLE A, END DT FROM TABLE B
3/24/1994      4/20/1994      FROM TABLE B
4/21/1994       5/5/1994      FROM TABLE B
```

I'm open to any suggestions on how to create TABLE_C.  I have looked at trying to use MERGE, SSIS, cursors, etc. but keep getting bogged down or figure there must be an easier way.  Any suggestions on how to approach this?  I looked in "Similar Questions" and I can't seem to find my particular problem addressed.  If this basically has been asked, my apologies.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Sql-Server? 2012 added lead and lag functions that might be helpful here

Comment: what is your logic to take a record from TABLE A or TABLE B and what is your logic to take start dt from TABLE A?

Comment: I can't found range like this: `2/23/1994       3/9/1994      FROM TABLE A`. Can you explain logic more detailed?

Comment: Hamlet, sorry about typo.  Should read 2/25/1994.

Comment: Conrad, working in 2008R2.

Comment: Guido, using the 2 tables, I want to cover the entire range of dates, with the smallest ranges, if that makes sense.  That may mean taking start_dt from A and end_dt from B or vice versa.  That's why C has a range from 3/10 to 3/23.  B picks up at 3/24 again so it is sort of an "artificial" range.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to find a simple answer.  You are going to have to make a custom function or procedure which incorporates the exact logic you want.  Sorry.  Imagine some soft of iteration based on start_dt and length of time for each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct START_DT, END_DT from 
(
select START_DT, END_DT from #TABLE_A
union
select START_DT, END_DT from #TABLE_b
)b

You can change date format as you want and insert the selected data in the table. It is displaying merged data.

Comment: Ashish, that is a good start.  I will explore using this query.